# Call to a member function getPriceSum() on null

Tags: php, laravel

Call to a member function getPriceSum() on null is the error I get when I try to go to the cart page. I know the problem is within this one line of code as when I take it out the cart page appears.

```
{{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($item->id)->getPriceSum()}}
```

The purpose of this line is to increment the price in correlation with the quantity selected. I am unsure why this is throwing an error 
The getPriceSum function is from Darryldecode Shopping Cart for laravel. 
https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

```
/**
* get the sum of price
*
* @return mixed|null
*/
public function getPriceSum()
```

I'm new to laravel so if theres any other pieces of code you need to see I'd be more than welcome to show. I will provide the full blade page below

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h2>Your Cart</h2>


    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name of Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach ($cartItems as $item)
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">{{$item->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{$item->price}}

                    {{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($item->id)->getPriceSum()}}


                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{route('cart.update', $item->id)}}">

                        <input name="quantity" type="number" value="{{$item->quantity}}">

                        <input type="submit" value="Save">

                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{route('cart.destroy', $item->id)}}">Delete</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>


@endsection
```

It says the error is on this line of the library

```
public function getPriceSum()

  {

      return Helpers::formatValue($this->price * $this->quantity, $this- 
>config['format_numbers'], $this->config);

  }
```

And still throwing same error as initially

After PHP dump

[After PHP Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAx2.png)

Comment: Hi, did you try refactor like this? `{{$item->getPriceSum()}}`

Comment: Hi @OlegNurutdinov I just tried that and it didn't bring up an error but it also didn't increment the price when I increased or decreased the quantity, any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Its whenever I add the parenthesis after getPriceSum the error occurs if that helps

Comment: I added to my original post more about the error @OlegNurutdinov

Comment: Try dumping `Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($item->id)`, it is probably `null` and causing the error because you're calling a method on null.  
To do that, comment the buggy line and add:  
`@php dump(Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($item->id)) @endphp`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have edited the original post to show what happened when I did the php dump you suggested, thanks. @AugustoMoura